# When is the assert ( ) expression evaluated in a scope?

Tags: c++, c++11

I was trying to understand the `assert()` macro in C++ and I am confused as to when the assert statement is checked for its validity.
I created a class Pyramid where I wanted to check if the Class attributes are positive and so I created a `try() -> catch()` exception handling first and if I enter a negative value for instantiating a Pyramid Object, it throws the error( along with the `printData()` also being evaluated)

However is I go for `assert()` also by putting a statement `caught=false` in `caught() { }` the, neither the expression `std::cout<<errorText` nor the `printData()` gets evaluated and the program just throws an `Assertion "caught" failed.` error.

Can someone please explain how is the control executed when we put an `assert()` statement in the scope and why `std::cout<<errorText` nor the `printData()` are not getting evaluated at all?
The code is as below:

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class Pyramid
{
private:
    int length;
    int width;
    int height;
    float volume;

public:
    Pyramid(int l, int w, int h) : length(l), width(w), height(h)
    {
        volume = (1.0f / 3) * length * width * height;
    }

    void printData() const
    {
        std::cout << "\nLength : " << length
                  << "\nWidth : " << width
                  << "\nHeight : " << height
                  << "\nVolume : " << volume;
    }
    int Length() const
    {
        return length;
    }
    int Height() const
    {
        return height;
    }
    int Width() const
    {
        return width;
    }
    float Volume() const
    {
        return volume;
    }
};

int main()
{

    bool caught{true};
    try
    {   //Initialize Pyramid
        Pyramid pyramid( -11, 2, 3);

        //Print Check Pyramid Attributes 
        pyramid.printData();

        //Check for validity of attributes
        if (pyramid.Length() <= 0 || pyramid.Width() <= 0 || pyramid.Height() <= 0)
            throw std::string("\nAttributes cannot be zero or negative");
    }
    catch (std::string errorText)
    {
        std::cout << errorText;
        caught = false;
    }

    assert(caught);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I need to `#include <cassert>` to compile this, but otherwise your code exhibits the expected behavior on my machine. It prints the information and the error text and then a message about the assertion failing. Could you share some details about how you're compiling this?

Comment: Can't remember if `assert` prints to stderr or not. If it does, the order in which you see the output may be a bit odd.

Comment: I tried compiling it on Compile explorer. Here is the link for the same https://godbolt.org/z/8Yxcxzj86 
I even tried it in VSCode with the same result

Comment: Totally unrelated side note: There's a really neat hack I saw on SO once where you can print out a diagnostic message by abusing the comma operator. `assert("Caught message", caught);` will print out something along the lines of *Assertion: "Caught message", caught*

Comment: If there is data buffered up inside `cout` , is it guaranteed to be printed when assert terminates the program? `assert` calls `abort`, and `abort` is pretty hardcore in its exit.

Comment: @user4581301 Looks like not. If we flush `cout` before the assertion, we get the expected behavior on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/zsj75fYj7).

Comment: Here we go: [Quoting cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/abort) *Destructors of variables with automatic, thread local (since C++11) and static storage durations are not called.* Program gets out of dodge and doesn't do much clean up. Unflushed data can die in the buffer.

Comment: Rats took too long checking my facts. Should have started with cppreference and not the C++ Standard.

Comment: Add `std::endl` or `std::flush` to the `cout` statements.  I'd bet you will get the text you are seeking.  Your program is probably closing before it prints.

Comment: I'm going to have to play around with catching SIGABORT after asserting to see what manner of evil I can get up to. It won't be safe to flush in a signal handler, but I bet there's still some room for fun.

Comment: Diagnostic output should normally be written to [`std::cerr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cerr) instead of `std::cout`. This has the advantage that in contrast to `std::cout`, `std::cerr` is unbuffered, which means that all output is automatically flushed.

Comment: @Matt Thanks a lot!! It helped

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When is the assert ( ) expression evaluated in a scope?

`assert` is evaluated when the execution reaches it. Same as most expression statements (`assert` itself is a macro, but it will expand into an expression statement).

> neither the expression std::cout<<errorText nor the printData() gets evaluated

You've assumed wrongly. They will get evaluated.

What may happen instead, is that because the program is terminated, there is no cleanup of static objects. And because there is no cleanup, `std::cout` is not destroyed. And because `std::cout` isn't destroyed, the output that you have inserted is not necessarily flushed to the standard output stream and instead remains in the buffer of `std::cout`. In which case you wouldn't see the output in the terminal.

Comment: It may be worth noting that `std::cout` can be flushed explicitly by calling `std::cout << std::flush;`.

Comment: doesnt that make `assert` rather useless?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel once it terminated you can't flush the stream

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number depends on whether it's more important to nuke the program or make sure all of the data got out. Heck, if the program's broken enough to assert, can you trust the data it put out?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number No. `assert` can be quite useful. (Although it's arguably not the best solution to all use cases). Just don't terminate the program while you have output waiting in the buffer (assuming you trust the state of the program enough to not make things worse). `once it terminated you can't flush the stream` No, but you can flush before.

Comment: i misread question and then misinterpreted the answer. Will leave the silly comments because now already others refer to it

Comment: @eerorika Thanks for the clarification. Helped in gaining knowledge about the basics of standard output stream in C++
@AndreasWenzel Yeah I checked, the output stream get flushed when it put `std::flush` in the code before the assert() statement.